# cv::UMat::convertTo in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I want to convert a `UMat` to a different type.

I already tried using the `UMat` method `convertTo` which got me following error:

`AttributeError: 'cv2.UMat' object has no attribute 'convertTo'`.

I also tried using the `numpy` method `np.float32` which appearently doesn't work with `UMat`:

`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'cv2.UMat'`

I would use a numpy array but I need it in the `UMat` format for other methods.

This is the code in question:

```
array255 = cv2.UMat(int(height), int(width), type=cv2.CV_8UC1, s=(255))

...

hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

...

lhsv = cv2.split(hsv_frame)
s = cv2.subtract(array255, lhsv[1])
v = cv2.subtract(array255, lhsv[2])
#s = s.convertTo(cv2.CV_32F)
#v = v.convertTo(cv2.CV_32F)
s = np.float32(s)
v = np.float32(v)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UMat` has method `get()`, returning a `numpy.array`. Call it, than use `numpy` type conversion methods. E.g.

```
array255f = array255.get().astype('f')
```

Than you can convert it back to `UMat`:

```
array255fum = cv2.UMat(array255f)
```

`array255fum` will be of type `cv2.CV_32F`.

Comment: Perfect, that works and also helped my understanding of ```UMat``` a bit.